# Can I apply for a faculty position after 14 years of postdcoc?

Tags: phd, postdocs, faculty-application, tenure-track

I did my pHD in 2007. After that I worked on several univeristies as post doc and postdoctoral associates. I mentored students, did TA, wrote proposals, and worked with industrial collaboration projects.

What is my possibility to become a tenure faculty ?

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/61880/40589

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you do this? And it would help to have an idea of your productivity (publications).

Comment: Probably the hiring committee will look at your recent publications, not your Ph.D. from 15 years ago.  Even a current academic, applying for a new job, will base the application on recent publications, not on something from 15 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly apply. There is nothing to prevent that. But, like any candidate you have to meet the qualifications and present a positive case.

Depending on your field, you may be expected to have a pretty full CV, with papers and such and also good letters of recommendation (in those places where they are valued). You might also be asked to explain why you spent so long as a post doc. That may be easy to do, depending on your research and its outcomes.

But only a hiring committee will be able to say whether you can be offered a tenure-track position.

And, as you make applications, it is better to cast a wide net and not focus on only a very narrow subset of universities. Match any application to the needs of that institution as best you can discover.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably become a professor with that sort of experience at some institutions worldwide, but in the USA for example, the university will most likely want "the big names" in the field. That can be a PhD student with little experience but big impact (very rare), or otherwise rising stars. That is quite difficult to achieve, and I suppose is not directly related to experience.

But, obtaining experience leads I suppose "monotonically" to better chances of a faculty position, no doubt. 14 years is easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly apply but the chances are slim: there’s a point when the work you did in the past is no longer relevant for your future research prospects.  Maybe underwater basketweaving was a big deal 14years ago, but now all the rage is in zero-gravity painting.

The difficulty is that you will be compared in all categories - publications, student supervision, grants - with people 14 years out of a PhD.  In particular,
you will need to present the case that *recent* work would be relevant for *future* work: after all, hiring committees will not hire you for the work you did in the past but for the work you will do for them in the next so many years.

There might also be the technical difficulty of salary expectations.  Normally, someone with 14 years of experience will command higher salary than a more junior candidate, and the $$ might simply not be there to hire in the upper pay grades.

Comment: I doubt the OP's education has become obsolete while a post doc. It isn't like they were a life guard in Hawaii. But they might need to be a bit flexible on salary unless they have been very productive over the 14 years. Productivity wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Buffy realistically however very few people are hired on a tenure stream position 14 years out of a PhD, even in teaching universities.

Comment: True enough, but everyone is an individual and needs to make their case.